# How to create a Java Servlet application in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition with Java EE 7 and Glassfish 4?

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, glassfish

I want to create a Java Servlet. I know nothing about the Java ecosystem except a tiny bit of the Java language.

I already had JDK 1.8.0_65 on my machine and JRE 6 as well.

I looked up [this article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/developing-a-java-ee-application.html). It said I could use Glassfish as the application server. Java 7 EE comes with Glashfish 4.

So, I went to [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-7-downloads-1956236.html) and downloaded the **Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 7 SDK Update 2** for Windows. I am running 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium. It is presently a 128 MB download.

To install it, I looked up the very unhelpful instructions on [this web page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/javaee7sdk-install-1957708.html#install). That didn't help me because this page says almost nothing except: please unzip your download and then ???, and then profit.

But [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPsq3H0LNj8) helped me. Here's what I did.

I unzipped the folder and placed the uncompressed folder in my **%Program Files%\Java** folder. Then I ran the **%Program Files%\Java\java_ee_sdk-7u1\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\startserv.bat** file and browsed to the Url **http://localhost:4848** and the Glassfish Console started up just fine.

Then as per the instructions in the **Creating a project** section on [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/developing-a-java-ee-application.html), I opened up the **IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.2.1** IDE, which I already had installed previously, and clicked the **Create New Project** menu item in the start-up dialog.

However, in the **New Project** dialog, I do not see the option **Java Enterprise** as the article suggested. This is what my **New Project** dialog looks like.

[image]

What do I do now? I just want to create a simple Web application using servlets.

One difference I note is that [the article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/developing-a-java-ee-application.html) suggests that I have IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition, which I do not have. Is it not possible to create servlets using the community edition of IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: "Is it not possible to create servlets using the community edition of IntelliJ IDEA?" - yes it is. But your question is really about easy setup and management of a JEE project, and that would require the use of Maven or Gradle which the community edition does support out of the box.

Comment: Intellij community can be used for Servlets, you just do not have as many easy wizards and helpers for creating it.  And if you know nothing about them, it is good for you to learn to do that anyway.

Comment: See also [Is it possible to adopt IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition for web-development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553672/is-it-possible-to-adopt-intellij-idea-community-edition-for-web-development)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA Comunity Edition can't create Java Enterprise applications, but Ultimate Edition can ([IntelliJ IDEA Editions comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)). Use it, or some another free IDE [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/), [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) etc.

Comment: I tried with Eclipse but now have a problem using that as well. I have described the problem in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39073274/303685

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is your best option to **just make it work right now** If you download the Java EE version of netbeans everything is ready to go. Also most of the canonical getting started documentation focuses on/ is highly coupled with Netbeans development.

This is a Netbeans focus/opinionated setup guide from oracle.
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/usingexamples001.htm

Comment: Thank you. After writing a few servlets in Java, I ultimately want to write a proper servlet applicaiton in Kotlin. While I know IntelliJ and Eclipse have support for Kotlin, I was wondering if Netbeans also does?

Comment: **Kotlin Support from Netbeans is non-existent**
There are possibly community plugins this is one i just found:
https://github.com/Baratynskiy/kotlin-netbeans
But I would *guess* that it is not stable, because the latest release is **0.1.0-alpha**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think intellij idea will read what you installed. Try using maven, and select webapp. Then search for the maven respiratory for servlets. I'm note even sure it will work. Your best bet for a free ide would be eclipse. Its not the best for beginners, but it's better than netbeans. Or you could simply waste your money on the paid version.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot create Enterprise applications in intellij community ,But you can run the servlets using google appengine in intellij community.I recommend you read this  [post](https://medium.com/@rameshlingappa/google-appengine-with-gradle-intellij-dc881230662e)