# How to create a servlet using Eclipse Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

Please be gentle with me. I just know a tiny bit of the Java language, which I don't find challenging at all. But I know nothing about the daunting ecosystem of IDE's and tools and packages just to get started building something useful.

I just want to build a servlet. I have Java SE 8 in the folder **%Program Files%\jdk1.8.0_65**. In the program files folder, I also have **jre1.8.0_65**, **jre6** and **java_ee_sdk-7u1** (Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 7 SDK Update 1).

I also have Eclipse Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) installed.

All of this is installed on my 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium laptop.

I am following [this tutorial](http://o7planning.org/en/10169/java-servlet-tutorial) to create a servlet using Java with the Eclipse Java Mars IDE.

Following the instructions laid out in that article, I clicked **File** -> **New** -> **Other**.

[image]

However, the dialog box I get after doing that does not have the item **Web** as depicted in the picture in that article.

My dialog box looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be working in **Eclipse for Java**.,

Download **Eclipse for JEE** to get Web Development features.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/neonr or http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/mars2

Comment: Thank you. I'm giving that a try now.

Comment: I downloaded Eclipse for JEE Mars2 and it now works like a charm. Thank you. :-)

Comment: You are welcome @Water Cooler :-)