# Where in Eclipse do I see a project's build progress?

Tags: java, eclipse

**Question**

I am using Eclipse for Java EE, Mars 2, and when I build a project, I don't see any output in the **Console** window.

Where do I see project build progress and errors?

Comment: There is a Problem view, where you can see compile Errors and warnings

Comment: @Jens Oh, thank you.

Comment: Just for suggestion Windows->Show View->Others->Problems

Console appears in tab with Problem view

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Window -> Show View -> Progress` (for progress)

`Window -> Show View -> Markers (or) Problems` (for errors)

Comment: Thank you. 7 more minutes before I mark this as the right answer.

Comment: is there a way to see progress histry?

Comment: The markers View seems to give me a better indication of the errors than the problem view, which often shows issues even when the app seems to have compiled just fine. I see no evidence of build progress in the progress view, nothing on the lower status  bar. I'm new to Eclipse/Spring Tool Suite, which is what I am using.

Answer (score 0):

you can see it in the right lower corner of IDE just above task bar.

or

Just configure the problem view to show only problems
Click on the small triangle at the far right of the view.
In the popup menu, select "Configure Contents..."
Select each item in the "Configurations" list and click on "Scope: On any element in the same project"

If you want to see the compiler working, you need open the "Progress" view.

Plus

The built-in Java compiler is tightly integrated with Eclipse and JDT, and provides the source indexing that enables powerful IDE features such as refactoring and quick fix.

Plus, it enables incremental build in background after each file modification, hence no visible "java" invocation.

Comment: Nope. There's nothing there. I would have found it by now if it was that in plain a view.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the lower right corner; you should see something like

[image: screenshot of build progress]

there. Please note: you might only see that "going" for larger projects. Smaller projects might be built "instantly" without you getting much feedback on that.

In addition to that, you might check the *Problems* tab/page. Our project has like 100K warnings; so you can nicely see the number of warnings growing in there.

[ hint: resist the temptation to introduce so many warnings to your project that these counters matter to you ]

Finally: this might depend a bit on the **View** that you are using. Are you using the "Java EE" view; or just "Java"?!

Comment: I actually looked everywhere and I don't see that happening at all in my IDE. I don't see anything like that in any corner.